# Arrange array of objects by corresponding array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings in a specific order and would like to arrange a different array of objects to match the original array order.

```
var arrangement = ["third", "first" "second"];

var myObjs = [
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "first"
  },
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "second"
  },
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "third"
  }
];
```

So that the output would be:

```
var myObjs = [
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "third"
  },
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "first"
  },
  {
    name: "thing",
    position: "second"
  }
];
```

Any ideas on a good way to approach this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `indexOf` function of the first array on the current elements you are sorting:

```
myObjs.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return arrangement.indexOf(a.position) - arrangement.indexOf(b.position);
})
```

Comment: Nice and straightforward, but can be a lot of processing if `arrangement` isn't small.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a map (an object) keyed by the `position` values from the first array, with the index of each entry as the value; e.g.:

```
var map = arrangement.reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
    obj[value] = index;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Then I'd use `Array#sort` on `myObjs` with a comparator function that looks up the `position` values of the two entries it's given on the `map`:

```
myObjs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return map[a.position] - map[b.position];
});
```

Live example:

```js
var arrangement = ["third", "first", "second"];

var myObjs = [
        {
            name: "thing",
            position: "first"
        },
        {
            name: "thing",
            position: "second"
        },
        {
            name: "thing",
            position: "third"
        }
    ];

var map = arrangement.reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
    obj[value] = index;
    return obj;
}, {});

myObjs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return map[a.position] - map[b.position];
});

snippet.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(myObjs));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to "index" the object array:

```
var objpos = {};
objects.forEach(function(obj, ix) { objpos['!' + obj.name] = ix; });
```

Then you can build the result

```
var result = arrangement.map(function(name) {
    return objects[objpos['!' + n]];
});
```

The `!` is my habit of always adding it in front of keys when using objects as dictionaries (to avoid problems with the key `"constructor"`).